# How do you serialise/deseialise DER/BER into a naviagable structure C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, openssl, der, asn.1

Does anyone know of anyway in C/C++ where it is possible to serialise an unknown DER into a structure which can be navigated.

For Example:

Say I have the DER

```
Hello ::= SEQUENCE {
   myInt INTEGER,
   myBool BOOLEAN,
   myStr UTF8String
}
```

as an encoding. I want the ability to parse this sequence into a C Structure where I could navigate. I.E.

```
unsigned char *myDer = { 0x30, ..., 0x02, 0x01,0x12, ... };
AsnObj obj(myDer);
AsnObj *children = obj.getChildren();
for(int i=0;i<children->size();++i) {
   AsnObj child = children.getChild(i);
   /* Do something with this child */
}
```

I have looked at various tools like asn1-compiler, but this seemed like it assumed you know what the structure is.

I also looked at snacc, but I was struggling to get anything compiled with this and again seemed a bit obtuse. I think ffasn1c would work, but it requires a license which I can't get.

I known OpenSSL would have to do something similar, like `d2i_X509` but this is assuming it's an X509 which it isn't. Is there a method on OpenSSL that would enable you to parse and iterate over a DER?

Any help much appreciated.

Calum

Comment: _"...know of any C/C++ libraries..."* - requests for library and tool recommendations are off-topic for this website.  I've not used it, but believe [another StackOverflow-family site called Software Recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) allows such questions.

Comment: Simple question change to hopefully make that fall within the guidelines.

Comment: ASN.1 is pretty basic, you could just roll your own. In my (rather old) experience you will pay a lot for a commercial library, so that's what we ended up doing.